# Magento 2.4 installation issue on windows machine

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, installation, magento2.3.1, magento2.4

I have downloaded magento 2.4 and trying to install on windows machine but while hitting "localhost/magento-24/" it is not showing install button. I don't know the reason can some help me in this. Please find the screenshot below. [image]

Comment: Magento 2.4 has removed graphical installation. Here you have the different methods to install it: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/bk-install-guide.html

Comment: Install Magento using composer, https://jeevatech.blogspot.com/2019/11/install-magento-233-wamp-3-windows-7.html

Comment: Hi Zus I followed this url but got below error. ""InsearchConfig.php" line 81 : could not validate a connection to Elasticsearch. No alive nodes found in your cluster."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install https://www.elastic.co/downloads/past-releases/elasticsearch-7-6-0. Go to bin directory from command prompt and run :-

1. elasticsearch-service.bat install
2. elasticsearch-service.bat start

Then run the command:-

php bin/magento setup:install --base-url= http://localhost/yourrootfoldername/ --db-host=localhost --db-name= magento2 --db-user= root --db-password= password --admin-firstname=test --admin-lastname=testadmin --admin-email=test@gmail.com --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_US --currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --cleanup-database --sales-order-increment-prefix="ORD$" --session-save=db --use-rewrites=1

Should work like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

try you following way :-

First your extract your magento 2 zip and open the command line and run below command :

```
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url= http://localhost/yourrootfoldername/ --db-host=localhost --db-name= magento2 --db-user= root --db-password= password --admin-firstname=test --admin-lastname=testadmin --admin-email=test@gmail.com --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_US --currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --cleanup-database --sales-order-increment-prefix="ORD$" --session-save=db --use-rewrites=1
```

After you run below commands :-

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento c:c
php bin/magento c:f
```

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: I ran this command but I have stucked at elastic search. How can I proceed further ? this is the error "InsearchConfig.php" line 81 : could not validate a connection to Elasticsearch. No alive nodes found in your cluster.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have not yet met the system requirements for Magento 2.4.

> As of Magento 2.4.0, MySQL is no longer used for search. You must use
> Elasticsearch. Magento is tested with Elasticsearch 7.6.x. You can use
> other versions at your discretion, but we recommend using the tested
> version of Elasticsearch.

See: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html#elasticsearch

Try one of the following links to setup Elasticsearch 7.6.x on your Windows machine:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/zip-windows.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/windows.html