# Having issue during installation of Magento 2.4.1

Tags: magento2, installation, bug, magento2.4.1

There is no link to start installation after setup of Magento 2.4.1
There is the only text as the image given below. how can I install and resolve this issue of Magento 2.4.1

[image]

Comment: Check this maybe it solve your issue..
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/320392/magento-2-4-installation-issue-on-windows-machine

Comment: I got this error :    [2020-11-10 11:01:01] main.CRITICAL: Class Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor does not exist {"exception":"[object] (ReflectionException(code: -1): Class Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor does not exist at /Users/ishukakria/Sites/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:24)"} []

Answer (score 1):

> `Run the below command in the command line:`

```
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url="http://localhost/magento241/" --db-host="localhost" --db-name="magento241" --db-user="root" --admin-firstname="admin" --admin-lastname="admin" --admin-email="admin@admin.com" --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="admin123" --language="en_US" --currency="INR" --timezone="America/Chicago" --use-rewrites="1" --backend-frontname="admin"
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Magento 2.4.0, the Web Setup Wizard is removed, and you must use the command line to [install](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli.html) or [upgrade](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html) Magento, as well as [modules](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/comp-mgr/upgrade-module.html) and [extensions](https://devdocs.magento.com/extensions/install/).

```
magento setup:install --base-url=http://127.0.0.1/magento2/ \
--db-host=localhost --db-name=magento --db-user=magento --db-password=magento \
--admin-firstname=Magento --admin-lastname=User --admin-email=user@example.com \
--admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_US \
--currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1 \
--search-engine=elasticsearch7 --elasticsearch-host=es-host.example.com \
--elasticsearch-port=9200
```

More information about `setup:install` can be found [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-install.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command in magento2 directory..

- php bin/magento setup:di:compile

Comment: got this error:    PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 10485760 bytes) in /Users/ishukakria/Sites/magento2/vendor/magento/module-wishlist/Model/Wishlist/AddProductsToWishlist

Comment: check this link......
https://www.groovypost.com/howto/howto/how-to-solve-php-fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-8388608-bytes-exhausted/

Comment: or go to php.ini fle and find ini_set()  and eplace it with ini_set('memory_limit', '-1')

Answer (score 0):

Ishu Kakrika, from Magento 2.4 the Accept and Setup button has been removed and we need to install only through the command line.

Refer to the below official document.
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-install.html